# Trying to code sign Mac app with Developer ID - get com.apple.developer.maps entitlement is not allowed (error code -67050)

Tags: maps, xcode6.1

I am code signing a Mac app using my Developer ID certificate so we can send it to beta testers.  Thanks to helpful articles here I made sure I have the right certificate and private key.  (This is a new app id)  When I select Developer ID and Archive, I select to distribute with Developer ID and it validates all the checks successfully (Using Xcode 6.1) and creates my app file.  When I launch it I crash with this in console (another great tip found here to check console for the REAL error):

```
killed com.[appname.OSX][pid 5946] because its use of the com.apple.developer.maps entitlement is not allowed (error code -67050)

11/7/14 11:26:23.263 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.VIPorbit.OSX.192016[5946]) Binary is improperly signed.
```

So, I know the docs say you cannot distribute an app with Maps outside of the MacApp Store, but I assume this mean selling Mac apps as is often done.  We are using the Mac App Store all the way.  Also I can successfully archive and submit to the Mac App Store and we're in review.

The challenge is we want to get this out to some beta folks and Maps is a key feature we've added.  I really don't want to go the old route with getting this Mac info and adding it to the provisioning file, defeats the purpose of the Developer ID option.

Anyone else experience this?

Answer (score 2):

**You can't distribute an application utilizing MapKit with a Developer ID.**

MapKit is an Mac App Store-only feature.

It's a shame that this is not clear from the documentation.

If you want to test the app before the Mac App Store submission, I am afraid you have to add beta-testers' machines to the provisioning profile and sign the bundle with a "Mac Developer: ..." code signing identity.